# Wrapping an HTML input button's text value over multiple lines

Tags: html, button, input, word-wrap

How do I move text to a new line in an HTML input element with the `type="button"` attribute?

I have following code:

```
<input type="button" id="btnTexWrapped" value="I see this is a long sentence here." style="width: 200px;" />
```

I want the button's text value to be wrapped in two lines.  I tried typing it into the next line in HTML. It didn't work as I expected:

```
<input type="button" id="btnTexWrapped" value="I see this is a long 
sentence here." style="width: 200px;" />
```

I also tried using all options of `white-space` with fixed `width: 200px;`, but still nothing works.

I am OK with statically fixing the length, width, or other values: as the control is not going to change.

Comment: Try to use the `<button></button>` tag.

Comment: It didn't work for me when I tried it with the <button> tag, e.g. <button>Hello &#13;&#10; World</button> (in Chrome v38.0)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this, you can see how it works instantly:

```
<input type="button" value="Carriage&#13;&#10;return&#13;&#10;separators" style="text-align:center;">
```

Comment: No longer works in Chrome (at least since version 48)

Answer (score 24):

```
white-space: normal;
```

should work

Comment: This no longer works for chrome (as of 48.0.2564.97 m)

Comment: @RMN this should be the default answer. Works

Answer (score 15):

You can use button tag

> <button> I see this <br/>is a long <br/> sentence
>   here.</button>

Comment: Be aware that this doesn't work properly in Safari. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67933568

Answer (score 7):

For anyone reading this question 4 years later, I would like to add some clarifying details. Lokesh's answer is the correct one (*not* the accepted answer), but the initial question is based on a misunderstanding of how HTML works, which no one has addressed.

HTML is not a white-space significant language. That is, any new lines are completely ignored by the browser. While you can (and should!) put new lines in your HTML code in order to write readable, maintainable HTML, it will (almost) never affect the end result (I won't get into exceptions here).

As Lokesh indicated, you can use the `<br />` tag to force a new line. Another common way is to use block level elements, such as `div` or `section`.

> A number of elements are set to block by the browser UA stylesheet. They are usually container elements, like `<div>`, `<section>`, and `<ul>`. Also text "blocks" like `<p>` and `<h1>`. Block level elements do not sit inline but break past them. By default (without setting a width) they take up as much horizontal space as they can.

This is a quote from https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/, which is a very good reference on the different properties for the `display` attribute.

Additionally, I don't recommend trying to use any of the other suggested solutions which require putting encoded newline symbols inside the `value` attribute. This is pushing the `input` tag beyond was it was designed for. If you need more complex content for a button, the `button` tag is more appropriate. In fact, I generally don't think there's ever good reason to use `<input type="button">` instead the `button` tag. It's much more semantic, easier to read, and is infinitely more flexible - for example, in allowing breaks and other elements (such as images!) inside it.

Just a bit of knowledge and a few recommendations from a professional web developer... :)

Comment: Completely agreed with you. However, what if I need an `<input type="submit"`? Replacing it with a `<button>` and writing custom logic for submitting a form because of a *single* linebreak... oh, I think it's overingeneering.

Comment: I don't see how using a `<button>` tag could possibly be termed over-engineering. There is no extra (much less custom) logic to make a button work... you just use `<button type="submit">` and it works out of the box. In fact, it's best practice to use HTML5 elements such as `button` instead of `input`. See the notes section on MDN here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Notes

Comment: Thanks for `<button type="submit">`!

Comment: Be aware that this doesn't work properly in Safari. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67933568

Answer (score 3):

I had come cross type of  requirement in my one of the project,i resolved like given below.

use html encoding string

`<input button type="submit" value="This is button &#x00A; two line text" />`

`&#x00A;`

for splitting the text in value attribute of the button tag

Hope this will help you..

Answer (score -11):

Just press enter in the middle of the value, like this:

```
<input type="button" id="btnTexWrapped" value="I see this is a long 
sentence here." style="width:200px;"/>
```