# How to newline in HTML Button?

Tags: html

Hello guys how to newline or break inside a input button?. I have this code:

```
<input type="button" id="Button" value="RECOMMEND DISAPPROVE" disabled="disabled" style="width:125px; height: 35px;"/>
```

I tried `<br/>` but not working..

Comment: Sorry for being beginner but i'm using this button to disapprove a request but word "RECOMMEND" is all i can see.

Comment: Did you try &#010;

Comment: You can make a line break using the CSS `word-break` property or CSS `flex-wrap`property. Find how to use them here: [How to Create Button with Line Breaks](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/button-with-line-breaks.html) at W3docs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to use the `<button>` attribute as `<input>` doesn't support the newline tags. So you could do this for example:

```html
<button type="button" id="Button" disabled="disabled" style="width:125px; height: 35px;">RECOMMEND<br />DISAPPROVE</button>
```

*You may want to remove the button width/height as the text doesn't fit well in the button*

I hope this will help you.

Comment: You're welcome! If this solution worked for you, you can accept this answer as solved if you want to :-)

Comment: @YurkZ Under the votes from this answer, you see a gray mark, of you click on it you will mark this answer as solved :-)

Answer (score 4):

[CodePen solution](http://codepen.io/anthonyastige/pen/gMgJGa)

```
<button>Line one<br/>line two</button>
```

**It appears `<input type="button">` doesn't support line breaks**

- [Wrapping an HTML input button's text value over multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048499/wrapping-an-html-input-buttons-text-value-over-multiple-lines) (Top answer broke in Chrome 48)