# Are buttons in Safari broken?

Tags: html, button, safari

I have some buttons with a single line text, let's call them `short`.
I have other buttons with multiple lines of text, let's call them `long`.

In Chrome, all the buttons look fine and the same.
But in Safari, `long` looks different from `short`.
`long` looks like it's being pressed.
When I press `short`, the button will become blue.
When I press `long`, the button will become dark gray.

**How can I make `long` look and act like `short`?**

---

Here's a minimal case of how to recreate the problem:

```html
<html>
<body>
  <button>Single-line button</button>
  <button>Multi-line<br/>button</button>
  <button>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a picture of the problem:

[image: Different buttons]

There are three buttons:

1. A button that has little text so that everything is on one line
2. A button that has an explicit line break
3. A button that has a lot of text that causes word wrapping and therefore multiple lines

Both 2. and 3. look different from 1.